# Difficulties Leveraging TestNG with PreExisting Test Architecture

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

The Following is a beat down (minimal)  representation of my class structure, note that there is only one integration point with TestNG in the structure (the @Test annotation on the abstract class).

```
public abstract class AbstractValidator2{
protected WebDriver driver;
protected String url;

public AbstractValidator2(String url, WebDriver driver) {
    this.url = url;
    this.driver = driver == null ? new ChromeBrowser() : driver; //Setup Selenium
    //more common setups reports, utilities, etc...
}
@Test
public void run() {
    setup();
    validate();
    tearDown();
}
public void setup() {}
public void tearDown() {}
public abstract boolean validate();
}
```

Now the following is an example of a test case that works great with the above structure.

```
public class sampletest extends AbstractValidator2{
    public sampletest() {
        super("www.google.com", null);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean validate() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Due to the fact the above has a no args constructor, it is very easy to use with TestNG. I can include this in any testing xml file, and configure it run in any which way. Great, life is good!

The next test below is where integration with TestNG goes down hill.

```
public class sampletest2 extends AbstractValidator2{
    Date date;
    public sampletest2(String url, Date date) {
        super(url, null);
        date = date;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean validate() {
        driver.get(url);
        Utils.wait(5000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this example I need to provide arguments to my constructor. I also need a new instance for every test case I would be looking to test. This rules out dataproviders alone. To add complexity I also need to run in parallel.  Factories actually do work, but there is an issue. It is seemingly impossible for me to select individual use cases when using the factory (I have to run them all, without a code change). On a daily basis I very often like to run use cases one off individually.

The solution I have came up with is the following.

```
public class sampletest2suite {
    @Test
    public void sampletest2google(){
        new sampletest2("https://www.google.com/", null).run();
    }
    @Test
    public void sampletest3bing(){
        new sampletest2("https://www.bing.com/", null).run();
    }
}
```

This structure has however crippled me and created a structure that prevents me from leveraging a lot of Testng's great features. My goal would be to leverage testng's xml configuration, so I could remove this duplicate code, and configuration from my java class structure.

I have also came up with another solution. This solution abuses inheritence and makes subclasses for the sole reason of providing a no args constructor in order to be compatible with testng. You can see the following stackexchange question on why this is a bad pattern: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257562/is-creating-subclasses-for-specific-instances-a-bad-practice

```
public class sampletest2suitealternativeapproach {
    public static class sampletest2Google extends sampletest2{
        public sampletest2Google() { super("https://www.google.com/", null); }
    }

    public static class sampletest2Bing extends sampletest2{
        public sampletest2Bing() { super("https://www.bing.com/", null); }
    }
}
```

Given the current issue(s), does anyone have any advice to get back on a healthier path.

Comment: Can you please let us know, how do you intend to pass values to your parameterized constructor? If the data source is something outside of the test code and if you are willing to toggle the data source to selectively run tests, then I think there's a way out.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan In short, my current solution is the sampletest2suite code block above. I'm not sure how else to get the parameters to the constructor. the sampletest2suite does allow me run parallel, and run individual test cases(can be configured with regular old testng xml). However it stops me from integrating further with testng in places I believe would be beneficial ie.`AbstractValidator2`. For example due to the fact I am running through @test on sampletest2suite instead of my test class's themselves; testng tags on the test class itself would be ignored.

Comment: Also when we run one off, we typically just use intellij's built in plugin. So we just fire off by clicking the play button. However we also have others that write one off xml's by hand, prior to manual runs.

Comment: Another solution would be to extend the test class in question, and provide the super the necessary args. This could get very messy with the class structure/files though. For example extend `sampletest2` for the sole purpose of providing a no args constructor for the child class and providing the super args, and name the new class `sampletest2Google`. And repeat for bing `sampletest2Bing`

Comment: I've updated my question to include the alternative solution aforementioned (for clarity purposed), that also has it's own set of unique downfalls.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. In your `sampletest2suite` you are hard-coding the values for those two parameters in those two methods. But how do you think you would pass those parameters ? Is it from a data source? If it were from a data source, what if you included the ability to enable/disable a row. That would give you selective execution capabilities no? And you could make use of factory and data provider to achieve what you are after right ?

Comment: I mean ultimately, if I have an instance of a test, idealy it would be runnable from testng flat out would be nice.
Or If I have a method that returns an instance of a class (specifically a class that has @test annotated within it), allow it to be included in the test xml.

Comment: To your point, I could use a Factory.
One way that would work is if on the Factory I had an optional parameter `testName`
If not provided run all test cases.
If a string is provided, map each string to a specific test case/instance.
This also feels a bit hacky to me.

Comment: Have you explored leveraging a `org.testng.IObjectFactory2` which kind of sounds like is what you are needing. This would facilitate the creation of Test class instances based on the class name passed to it. So you can build a complete mapping of how to instantiate which class using what parameters. And in order to ensure that this implementation gets invoked all the time, you basically leverage a `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener` which can be injected via a Service Provider Interface. Do you think that is an option?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I have created a git repository, so anyone can easily run my current example problem. I have also included 3 work around solutions I was able to get operational, each with their own respective testng xml. https://github.com/Warfront1/TestNG-Create-Individual-Instances. Also is there a better way to communicate with the testng team?

Comment: Yes I went through that GitHub link you shared. But you didn't answer my question. Have you explored `IObjectFactory2` ? You can communicate with the TestNG team by posting on either the [TestNG-Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/testng-users) forum or the [TestNG-Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/testng-dev) forum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170195/discussion-between-copy-and-paste-and-krishnan-mahadevan).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some features of TestNG that, if used, would make your life easier. `setup()` and `tearDown()` should be annotated appropriately with `@Before*` and `@After*`. That will trigger them to run at the appropriate time without having to call them in some `run()` method. Instantiating the driver should be in `setup()`. A best practice is to create a browser instance, use it for 1 test, and destroy it. That keeps each run separate and avoids cross-contamination of runs (one run goes bad and messes up later runs, etc.).

Here's a simple example that I hope will help you understand how to use a dataprovider with TestNG to do something like what you want.

```
public class TestNg
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public void test(String url, String title)
    {
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), title, "Verify title");
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup()
    {
        String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        return new Object[][] { { "http://www.google.com", "Google" }, { "http://www.bing.com", "Bing" } };
    }
}
```

There are a LOT of ways to do dataproviders with TestNG. This is just one of them. You would know better which method might fit your needs and can investigate the official docs and pick the one that's right for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look over my problem. I am familiar with dataproviders and Factories. In fact a a testng factory can provide me almost everything I need. The issue is I can't select individual test cases from a factory or a dataprovider. I am forced to run all of the cases/tests, unless a code change is made. Also a dataprovider will not work, as you mentioned driver cross contamination and other nasty things will happen. The way the original framework dealt with this (and still does) is for each test class to have a fresh unique instance of the test class.

Comment: You should clarify your question to target the specific issue you refer to here. That isn't covered in your question. For my example and the issue with selecting individual test cases, you just alter/filter your test data. Take your data out of code and move it elsewhere. You could put it in a db or Excel or whatever. There are lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of solving your problem.

Ingredients:

1. A custom annotation that would represent the parameters to be injected into every test.
2. A base class per variant of your tests (or) you can even have one generic base class that just works with Objects.
3. An implementation of `IHookable` implementation in your base class, that would play the role of patching the call to the test, after figuring out the right parameters to be injected.
4. An object factory (if required) which would be responsible for creating objects to be instantiated into tests (something like what Spring does).

Here's the sample

**The annotation**

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface InjectParameters {
  String url() default "";

  String getComplexClass() default "testngImplementation.acomplexclass";
}
```

**The base class from which your tests would extend**

```java
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.internal.ClassHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AbstractValidator implements IHookable {

  public AbstractValidator() {
    // more common setups reports, selenium, utilities, etc...
  }

  public void setup() {}

  public void tearDown() {}

  @Override
  public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
    System.out.println("We made it to run on the Abstract Validator 2");
    setup();
    Object[] parameters = callBack.getParameters();
    Object[] injected = getParametersToInject(testResult);
    if (parameters.length == injected.length) {
      System.arraycopy(injected, 0, parameters, 0, parameters.length);
    }
    callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
    tearDown();
  }

  private Object[] getParametersToInject(ITestResult testResult) {
    List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    InjectParameters toInject =
        testResult
            .getMethod()
            .getConstructorOrMethod()
            .getMethod()
            .getAnnotation(InjectParameters.class);
    if (toInject != null) {
      parameters.add(toInject.url());
      parameters.add(ClassHelper.newInstance(ClassHelper.forName(toInject.getComplexClass())));
    }
    return parameters.toArray(new Object[0]);
  }
}
```

**A sample test class**

```java
public class TestCreation extends AbstractValidator {
  @Test
  @InjectParameters(url = "https://www.google.com/")
  // The @Parameters is being used just as a place holder here. To prevent TestNG from triggering
  // Validations saying that parameter required but not provided. I think this would be fixed
  // as part of fix for https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/564 which would be available in
  // TestNG 7.0.0

  @Parameters({"url", "a"})
  public void sampletest2google(@Optional String url, @Optional acomplexclass a) {
    System.err.println("URL is " + url);
    System.err.println("Complex object  is " + a.toString());
  }

  @Test
  @InjectParameters(url = "https://www.bing.com/")
  @Parameters({"url", "a"})
  public void sampletest3bing(@Optional String url, @Optional acomplexclass a) {
    System.err.println("URL is " + url);
    System.err.println("Complex object  is " + a.toString());
  }
}
```

Further enhancements, to suite the specifics of your problem.

If you would like to make this as generic as possible, then you could consider doing the following:

- Since TestNG supports Guice Injection, explore it, to take care of Object instantiation and re-use of the same, for your `@Test` methods.
- If every test basically needs to work with a different set of parameters, maybe you could define the method name as one of the parameters in your custom annotation and thus the base class's implementation which parses the custom annotation would end up becoming a generic one (Similar to what TestNG does when you specific a data provider name)